# How to delete local file(s) if java application crashes?

Tags: java, file-io

I am building java application which downloads some files, modifies them and deploys it to destination. Once the file is deployed, the program will delete all local files.

```
try{  
  ...
  //logic to download/modify files  
}catch(){  
  ...
  //catch exceptions
}finally{
  ...
  //logic to delete all the files
}
```

This works fine unless I terminate(ctrl+c in command prompt) the application in the middle of its execution.
Is there any way to delete same files in case application crashes?

Comment: You could try to install a shutdown hook. Those do get called for Ctrl-C (not sure for application crashes).

Comment: Another way could be to write them to a specific directory, and clear that directory on startup .

Comment: But I probably would not bother with that. Just put them in the normal system directory for temporary files. So if your regular `finally` does not clean them up, they will get removed eventually. And having them in place until then might actually help with debugging that crash.

Comment: When you terminate a program using `ctrl+c`, the application terminates instantaneously. There is nothing much you could do here. The best was is to apply @Berger solution

Answer (score 2):

try this document for shutdownhook - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        //Undo changes or delete files codes
    }
});
```